# The simplest way to edit certain cells in excel worksheet stored in SAP Web Repository?

Tags: abap

​What is the simplest way to edit certain cells in excel file located in SAP Web Repository? I have the layout of excel file (column names, width of column, etc.) with empty fields for data located in SAP Web Repository - transaction `smw0`, I want to edit only certain cells - save data in them and save new excel file.  I want something like read excel file, edit, for example, cell F8 and save something in it, show to user dialog for saving file and save that file. What is the best way to achieve that in my context?

Comment: Please focus at only one question. Ask a second question if needed. It's unclear if you ask how to read a file from the Web Repository, or how to change a cell in an "Excel file". Moreover, please tell us in what format is this Excel file: CSV, tab-delimited values, XLSX, etc.

Comment: I don't think you have the simplest, you have only one

Comment: Is it important that the end-user actually sees the excel file? Or would it be sufficient to have a regular application which lets the user do some input in some Dynpro fields and then when they click "save" their data gets saved to an excel workbook in the background?